# How to build an animation like Quicksand with jQuery only

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I would like to have an animation like the one in Quicksand

[Quicksand animation example](http://demo.monofactor.com/avalonstyle_wp_15/av-portfolio/jquery-sortable-4-columns/)

I do not want to use quicksand, because my setup is quite different and it makes everything way to complicated.

So if you would be able to give me a hint how this animation works and how I can get something like this going I would be very happy.

Thanks guys.

Comment: I don't see any special animation on that page...

Comment: @RikudoSennin Try clicking the `Sort:` menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **basic** concept behind it is to:

1. save the first collection for a moment, then load the second one with `display:hidden`.
2. Identify doublettes and hide everything else from the first collection.
3. Display the new collection, while keeping those that have doublettes `hidden`
4. Calculate the offset for the missing items, move the old ones to that position.
5. Unhide doublettes from new collection and remove old ones from DOM

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt seem like super complicated. Though not exactly the same as the example you provided.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-jquery/

or

http://www.gethifi.com/blog/a-jquery-plugin-to-create-an-interactive-filterable-portfolio-like-ours